# Got error "chmod function not defined" when trying to run any artisan or composer command in cpanel terminal

Tags: php, linux, laravel, composer-php, cpanel

I have a laravel project that I finished working on it locally, I wanted to upload the porject to hosting using cpanel
It's my first time working with cpanel and Linux, I have composer installed and php 8.1
now when I run composer install I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> Composer\Util\mkdir() in
> phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Util/Filesystem.php:

then I tried compressing the vendor directory in local and uploading it to laravel directory in cpanel
I linked the public folder to public_html
now when I try to access the domain I got a 500 error in the browser, I checked logs to find this error:

> Uncaught ReflectionException: Class "view" does not exist in /home/gozeroco/api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:875

also when I try to run any artisan command I get this error:

> Call to undefined function Illuminate\Filesystem\chmod()

please I need help, The website needs to be working today!

Comment: Did you tried `composer dump-autoload` ?

Comment: Yes and i get this error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Console\disk_free_space()

Comment: Just reinstall composer following the directions. https://getcomposer.org/download/